# Excel VBA: Click two buttons (shapes) that run two separate VBA scripts on spreadsheet open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet completely locked down and control all sorting and filtering through VBA. I also have another script that hides the sheet on close and saves the file automatically to keep that sheet hidden.

I've been trying to figure out how I can use VBA to 'click' on one button (shape) which would clear anything that's been filtered and then 'click' on another button (shape) which would sort the spreadsheet alphabetically. The buttons (shapes) already work perfectly with user-interaction but I would also like these buttons (shapes) to automatically get triggered when the sheet is opened.

The first button is assigned to macro, SearchBox, associated with the following VBA -

```
Sub SearchBox()

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim SearchString As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant

  Set sht = ActiveSheet

  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("DataTable").Range

  mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text

  If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
    SearchString = "=" & mySearch
  Else
    SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"
  End If

  For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
    If myButton.Value = 1 Then
      ButtonName = myButton.Text
      Exit For
    End If
  Next myButton

  myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)

  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:=SearchString, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

  sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""

End Sub
```

The second one is much more simple which just sorts the data table by that specific column -

```
Sub Sort_Name()

Dim oneRange As Range
Dim aCell As Range

Set oneRange = Range("A4:H1162")
Set aCell = Range("A4")

oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Basically, I'm still learning and I feel it's possible to just trigger these buttons with a script but I've yet to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There would be no need to click the buttons. You can directly call the code by using `Call SeachBox` in another code

Comment: Your thinking like a human. Just call the subroutine that the button is linked to directly in your code. Buttons are for humans.

Comment: So, on `Workbook_Open` event you will have two lines of code: `SearchBox /n SortCode` (/n represents new line, do not include in actual code).

Comment: Awesome, thank you all - when @JNevill said I was thinking like a human, i looked at the call the button itself was making and my issue was the main script was inside Sheet2 so it wouldn't work because it was an invalid call. It's working perfectly now and my masterpiece is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind for `ThisWorkbook`, you will be able to handle *workbook events*, including the `Open` event, which is fired by the workbook when it is opened.

Navigate to the module (double-click `ThisWorkbook` in the VBE's *project explorer* [Ctrl+R]), then locate the dropdowns at the top of the editor's code pane. From the left-hand dropdown, select `Workbook`; then, from the right-hand dropdown, select the `Open` event; the VBE automatically creates a method stub with the correct signature for you:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

End Sub
```

Notice that the underscore has a very special meaning in VBA; when naming your procedures (especially implicitly or explicitly `Public` ones), consistently stick to `PascalCase` and avoid `Snake_Case`; this may not matter *now*, but as you progress as a developer you'll come to appreciate *consistency* in naming, and when you start working with interfaces, that underscore-in-public-members thing will start making the difference between code that works and code that doesn't even compile: taking the good habits early will save you headaches later.

Now, you need to *invoke* two procedures in that handler.

When you do this:

```
oneRange.Sort Key1:=aCell, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

You're *invoking* the `Sort` method of the `oneRange` *object*, which is an *instance* of the `Range` class.

When you do this:

```
MsgBox "Hi!"
```

You're *invoking* the `MsgBox` function that's in the `VBA` library, under the `Interaction` module (find it in the *object browser* [F2]). This would be equivalent:

```
VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Hi!"
```

So, to *invoke* your `SearchBox` and then your `SortName` method, all you need to do is this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SearchBox
    SortName  'formerly known as Sort_Name
End Sub
```

Procedures *do* something - their names should always start with a verb, they're *actions*. "SearchBox" looks like a name, not an action. In programming, names are more like *classes* - a `Range`, a `Workbook`, etc.; consider renaming `SearchBox` to better convey what it *does*. If that's hard to do, it's likely because your procedure *does too many things* - like *getting the name to use for filtering*, and then *applying a filter to a specific table*, and then *clearing the text of some shape*.

You'll also want to watch out for implicit `ActiveSheet` references; currently `SortName` is assuming what the `ActiveSheet` is, and this is very likely to cause issues down the line.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to explain how I did what I was wanting to do is to look at what the button itself is calling to by right clicking it and clicking assign macro again. You'll see it look like this -

> 'YourSpreadSheetName.xlsm'!Sheet2.SearchBox

For me, what was throwing me off is I wasn't including the Sheet2 which is where the code is I'm trying to call.

By placing this code within the ThisWorkbook section with the Workbook_Open script, I was able to get it working the way I wanted it to -

> Call Sheet2.SearchBox

Thanks again for the help all who commented.

Comment: `Call` keyword is redundant and has been obsolete for 20 years. Also if `SearchBox` means to work against `Sheet2`, then it should be written against `Sheet2`, not `ActiveSheet`. Expect problems.